# iText7 - CopyPagesTo from pdfDocument to another and write to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I have two html strings, I'm trying to write both of them to 2 memoryStreams, then read one pdfDocument and CopyPagesTo to the other pdfDocument, then finally return the memoryStream with the combined documents.

```
{
    string Document = "<p>Hello to All</p>";
    string newPage = "<p>Additional Page</p>";
    var mainStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(mainStream))
    {
        pdfWriter.SetCloseStream(false);
        using (var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(Document, pdfWriter)) { }
    }
    mainStream.Position = 0;
    var newPageStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (PdfWriter pdfWriter1 = new PdfWriter(newPageStream))
    {
        pdfWriter1.SetCloseStream(false);
        using (var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(newPage, pdfWriter1)) { }
    };

    mainStream = addNewPage(mainStream, newPageStream);
    return mainStream;
}
```

Code to Add new page :

```
public static MemoryStream addNewPage(MemoryStream mainStream, MemoryStream newPageStream)
{
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(mainStream);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    pdfDoc.InitializeOutlines();
    PdfDocument addedDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(newPageStream));
    addedDoc.CopyPagesTo(1, addedDoc.GetNumberOfPages(), pdfDoc);
    mainStream.Position = 0;
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(mainStream))
    {

        writer.SetCloseStream(false);
        using (pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
        {
            int z = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
        }

    }
    addedDoc.Close();
    return mainStream;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You are both writing new stuff to and reading previous stuff from `mainStream` in `addNewPage` which can be tricky. In particular you have to first read the old contents before overwriting with new contents. You on the other hand first create a `PdfWriter writer` for writing to it (which will likely overwrite some existing content) and later you create a `PdfReader reader` for reading the original content. That cannot work. Furthermore, you use `writer` for two distinct `PdfDocument` instances. That cannot work either.